# How to efficiently aggregate panda dataframe based on substring matching?

Tags: python, pandas

My data frame looks like this

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['A, B', 'C, D', 'E, F', 'G'],
                   'col2': ['action1, action2', 'action1', 'action1, action2, action3', 'action4, action1']})


    col1    col2
0   A, B    action1, action2
1   C, D    action1
2   E, F    action1, action2, action3
3   G       action4, action1
```

I would like to group them to

```
    col1                col2
0   A, B, C, D, E, F    action1, action2, action3
1   G                   action4, action1
```

The order in the columns does not matter. Entries in col1 and col2 are both strings.

The logic behind it is:

1. E,F row contains action1, action2, action3. So A, B row which contains action1, and action2 is a subset of the E, F row.
2. Similarly, C, D row contains action1 which is a subset of A, B row, E, F row and G row, so C, D row can either be aggregate into E, F row or G row.

So I came up with this solution. Most likely not the most efficient version. Can anyone suggest a more optimal way to achieve it? At least from the code, the logic should be clear.

def dedup(df):
df = df.assign(DROP=False)

```
# forward merge will still be n^2 complexity...save for later
for i in range(0, len(df)):
    for j in range(0, len(df)):
        if (i == j) or df.iloc[i]['DROP'] or df.iloc[j]['DROP']:
            continue
        token_i = tokenize(df.iloc[i]['col2'])
        token_j = tokenize(df.iloc[j]['col2'])
        print(i, j, token_i, token_j)
        if(set(token_i).issubset(set(token_j))):
            df.iloc[j, df.columns.get_loc('col1')] = df.iloc[j]['col1'] + ", " + df.iloc[i]['col1']
            df.iloc[i, df.columns.get_loc('DROP')] = True
            print("i = ", i, df.iloc[i]['DROP'])
        elif(set(token_j).issubset(set(token_i))):
            df.iloc[i, df.columns.get_loc('col1')] = df.iloc[i]['col1'] + ", " + df.iloc[j]['col1']
            df.iloc[j, df.columns.get_loc('DROP')] = True
            print("j = ", j, df.iloc[i]['DROP'])

# drop everything drop marked as true
df = filter_rows_by_values(df, 'DROP', [True])
df = df.drop('DROP', 1)
return df
```

Comment: "Similarly, C, D row contains action1...so C, D row can either be aggregate into E, F row or G row". How is python supposed to know where you want this row aggregated/ How are we supposed to know in order to help? This question is too ambiguous. Perhaps you can [edit] to include a [mcve] showing the code you have already tried based on your own research, so that we can better understand your problem

Comment: @G.Anderson, i am thinking about a pseduo algorithm. updated in the post. Let me know if that clarifies things.

Comment: @G.Anderson, updated some real code with an initial attempt. Still pending on dropping the subset rows that got merged. Can you please help if it gets more clear now?

Comment: @G.Anderson, ok i came up with a full solution updated in the post. However, not optimal. WOuld like to know better way to do this. Can you remove the close tag or you need more context? Happy to provide more.

Answer (score 0):

This code should do the trick, I have decided to include extra columns just to make the logic clearer, you can clean this up as required.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['A, B', 'C, D', 'E, F', 'G'],
                   'col2': ['action1, action2', 'action1', 'action1, action2, action3', 'action4, action1']})
# split col2 by comma then split it into columns
df['col2'] = df['col2'].str.split(',')

# for each list in col2 check if it is a subset of any other list
# if it isnt return none
# if it is return the index of the list
df['col3'] = df['col2'].apply(lambda x: [i for i, y in enumerate(df['col2']) if set(x).issubset(y)][-1])
# now we can join all rows having the same number in col3
df['col4'] = df.groupby('col3')['col1'].transform(lambda x: ','.join(x))
# drop duplicate based on col4
df = df.drop_duplicates('col4')
df



    col1    col2    col3    col4
0   A, B    [action1, action2]  2   A, B,C, D,E, F
3   G   [action4, action1]  3   G
```